# Google Maps Javascript API v3 function getPlace() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google Place service to obtain the place details for a result coming out from an auto complete. The problem is that executing getPlace() request on my autocomplete object returns undefined for the variable (var place). Have been around this issue for days now, can't get on it.

My page is : [here](http://www.easyrideshare.com/testdebug.php), and 
the example I am following is [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

**error:**

TypeError: place is undefined [testdebug.php:232]

**main pieces of code:**

```
window['auto_'+inputFieldID+'_autocomplete'] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(inputFieldID));
window['auto_'+inputFieldID+'_autocomplete'].bindTo('bounds', map);

var place = window['auto_'+GoogleMapItems[LoopIndex]+'_autocomplete'].getPlace();

if (!place.geometry) 
{
console.log('cannot resolve rendering.');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure issue: loop index is used as 1 (value when loop finishes) instead of 0.

You can fix it using closure for loop index around event listener:

```
(function(LoopIndex) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(window['auto_'+GoogleMapItems[LoopIndex]+'_autocomplete'], 'place_changed', function() 
    ...         {
    });

})(LoopIndex);
```

This is one fix. Now another issue occurs: `points is not defined`

You are using variable `points` which seems has to contain information about markers. It is not defined in your code.

**Update:** Code as it is written now sets event listener to `departure` autocomplete only. See `for` loop. The only valid index is 0. If I load the page and write for example `s` into departure input I can select for example Sydney, New South Wales, Australia. After selection I get in console index 1 (which is wrong), `GoogleMapItems[LoopIndex]` returns `arrival` (which is wrong) and `places` are undefined which is correct because there is nothing in arrival autocomplete input. This is typical closure issue.

With my code change and selection from departure autocomplete I get loop index 0, `GoogleMapItems[LoopIndex]` returns `departure`, I get complete information for place, map is zoomed to Sydney and code fails because variable `points` is undefined.

So, variable `points` has to be defined somewhere and for loop has to be expanded to handle also other autocomplete parts of page.

Comment: Indeed, that is a JS specific case - More details can be found on this page : http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62. **However, this does not fix my issue _per se_ as the variable "place" is still undefined**. I think the issue comes from Autocomplete(), BindTO(), getPlace() being used with a wrong Google Maps object.

Comment: What you wrote in your comment is not true. I will update my answer to clarify.